# Shared Preferance in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, location, datastore

Display user location on home screen in Textbutton.icon in action widget where location is to be fetched from location screen which has 'use current location' button which is using geolocator function. so i have to store location of user and fetch the same or updated one automatically on home screen every time app opens.

I have tried shared preference for storing but failed.